# How to select an SVG element inside an <object> tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg, cross-domain

In my Angular appliation, I want to be able to select the embedded SVG element of an `<object>` tag using JavaScript or Angular jqLite.

Normally, to do this operation, one must write something similar to:

```
// Create <object> element of the SVG
var objElement = document.createElement('object');
objElement.setAttribute('type',"image/svg+xml");

// Assume $rootScope.b64 contains the base64 data of the SVG
objElement.setAttribute('data', $rootScope.b64);

// Append the <object> inside the DOM's body
angular.element(document.body).append(objElement);

console.log(objElement);
console.log(objElement.getSVGDocument());
console.log(objElement.contentDocument);
```

In my console, `objElement` returns the complete `<object>` with the `<svg>` element and its contents (assume that data attribute contains the full base64 data string (b64)).

```
    <object id="svgObject" data="b64" type="image/svg+xml">
          #document
             <svg>
             </svg>
    </object>
```

However, `getSVGDocument()` returns `null` and `contentDocument` returns

```
    #document
       <html>
          <head></head>
          <body></body>
       <html>
```

Why can't I retrieve the SVG element? How can I get the SVG element correctly? I've already looked into many articles and I just can't get the `<svg>` element. Could this have something to do with cross-origin policy?

Comment: You need to wait for the onload event of the object to fire before accessing its contents.

Comment: If I enclose the `getSVGDocument()` inside a onload event, I get `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getSVGDocument' on 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.`

Comment: Is this Chrome? I imagine you're blocked by its security model. You might try a different UA

Comment: Yes, I'm developing on Chrome. Do you mean User Agent? How can I toggle its security model?

Comment: Robert means try a different browser, like Firefox.  Chrome has a more restrictive security model.  For instance it disallows some things if you are using `file://` URLs.

Comment: I solved my problem guys, thanks. I decided to use FileReader's readDataFromString (I was using readDataFromURL) was using  and parse that instead.

Answer (score 5):

I was also unable to select the SVG using things like `document.querySelector("svg")` even though the SVG was clearly loaded in the DOM. Turned out I needed to do this:

```
var obj = document.querySelector("object");
var svg = obj.contentDocument.querySelector("svg");
```

Apparently there's a boundary between the main document and this sub-document, and you have to bridge the divide using `contentDocument`.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I have no trouble getting the `object`, but then `.contentDocument` returns null, even though I can clearly see the `#document` under the object in the Chrome devtools Elements and Console windows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems getSVGDocument() is deprecated. Have you tried something like `document.querySelector('object svg')` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see the object is because you are most likely probing for it before DOM load. Try:

```
// Create <object> element of the SVG
var objElement = document.createElement('object');
objElement.setAttribute('type',"image/svg+xml");

// Assume $rootScope.b64 contains the base64 data of the SVG
objElement.setAttribute('data', $rootScope.b64);

// Append the <object> inside the DOM's body
angular.element(document.body).append(objElement);

objElement.addEventListener('load', doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  console.log(objElement);
  var svgDoc = getSVGDoc(objElement);
  console.log('svgDoc', svgDoc);
}


function getSVGDoc(element) {
  console.log('getting obj');
  try {
    return element.contentDocument;
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      return element.getSVGDocument();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('SVG unsupported within this browser');
    }
  }
}
```